# How to analyse a non-inferiority trial using GEE in R?

Tags: r, p-value, hypothesis-test, correlated

I'm trying to analyse a non-inferiority trial in R. Since there are correlated observations and a population averaged interpretation seems fine, I want to use GEE.

To illustrate my problem, I will use the *muscatine* data that is embedded in the *gee* package in R.
The research question can be as follows, I want to investigate if the male participants in the muscatine data have a non-inferior obesity level compared to the females (so equivalent to testing if 'males' is a new, non-inferior drug compared to the standard drug 'females')

The outcome 'obese' and variable 'gender' are both binary, age and occasion are controlled for and continuous (not important tho)

- **The problem at hand:** I know how to perform a GEE in R, but how can I get p-values corresponding to a non-inferiority trial with **non inferiority margin equal to 0.01**? (So this is equivalent to testing H_0:β_1≤-0.01 vs H_a:β_1 > -0.01, where β_1 is the log-odds ratio ofcourse). I can only find online that GEE tests 2-sided hypotheses with β_1 = 0.

I used the following code:

```
library(gee)
data(muscatine)

data2 <- muscatine
data2$obese <- ifelse(muscatine$obese == 'yes', 0, 1)

x <- gee(obese ~ gender + age + occasion, id = id, family = binomial, corstr = "exchangeable", data = data2)
summary(x)
```

This gives me the following output concerning the coefficients:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Naive S.E. Naive z Robust S.E. Robust z
(Intercept)   1.7846     0.1152   15.49      0.1116    16.00
genderF      -0.1521     0.0620   -2.45      0.0626    -2.43
age          -0.0296     0.0113   -2.63      0.0110    -2.68
occasion     -0.0377     0.0298   -1.27      0.0310    -1.22
```

Thanks in advance to the savior!

Comment: I don't think you have set up the alternate hypothesis correctly for non-inferiority. See this paper for a discussion of the CI's and delta's for non-inferiority designs: https://www.or.org/files/Non-inferiority%20analyses,%20Mascha%20and%20Sessler.pdf I also agree with the closevoter (actually a migration vote). This sounds like a question for https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you for your comment! How is the alternative not correct? It is exactly the same as in the text above equation (12) on page 5 in the article you added, no? I will also move it to SE, thanks!

Comment: Yes, you are correct on that matter. I misread your formulation. I would now ask whether you understand how to set up an offset in a regression problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what that is or how this helps me, can you elaborate please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I retracted my closevote, because I think the issue lies in the OP not knowing how to set up an offset term in an R regression formula, so that's an R-centric problem and might be refused by stats.SE. An offset is a parameter in a model that is assumed to be measured with no uncertainty and is typically used to test against an H_0 other than 0. The other consideration in using offsets in R (and any modeling software with GLM's is that the offset needs to be entered with the link function in mind, so with a binomial model the offset needs to be the log of the effect size hypothesized in hte non-transformed data.

(Another issue with the code presented was that `muscatine` is not a data element in `pkg:gee` but rather in `pkg:geepack`)

```
if(!require(gee)){install.packages("gee"); library(gee)}
if(!require(geepack)){install.packages("geepack"); library(geepack)} # for muscatine
 
 data2 <- muscatine
 data2$obese <- ifelse(muscatine$obese == 'yes', 0, 1)
# add offset term with log of hypothesized H_0
 x <- gee(obese ~ gender + age + occasion+offset(rep(log(0.1), nrow(data2))), id = id, family = binomial, corstr = "exchangeable", data = data2)
#-----message from gee() --------
Beginning Cgee S-function, @(#) geeformula.q 4.13 98/01/27
running glm to get initial regression estimate
(Intercept)     genderF         age    occasion 
 4.00334630 -0.12601405 -0.02556356 -0.01632539 

 summary(x)
#---------output begins here----------------
 GEE:  GENERALIZED LINEAR MODELS FOR DEPENDENT DATA
 gee S-function, version 4.13 modified 98/01/27 (1998) 

Model:
 Link:                      Logit 
 Variance to Mean Relation: Binomial 
 Correlation Structure:     Exchangeable 

Call:
gee(formula = obese ~ gender + age + occasion + offset(rep(log(0.1), 
    nrow(data2))), id = id, data = data2, family = binomial, 
    corstr = "exchangeable")

Summary of Residuals:
        Min          1Q      Median          3Q         Max 
-0.97960924  0.02160615  0.02569267  0.02857506  0.03592698 


Coefficients:
              Estimate Naive S.E.   Naive z Robust S.E.  Robust z
(Intercept)  4.0872254 0.11518402 35.484310  0.11155396 36.638999
genderF     -0.1520871 0.06198955 -2.453431  0.06261391 -2.428966
age         -0.0295689 0.01126046 -2.625906  0.01102506 -2.681973
occasion    -0.0377399 0.02983178 -1.265090  0.03096084 -1.218956

Estimated Scale Parameter:  0.990456
Number of Iterations:  3

Working Correlation
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 1.0000000 0.5400174 0.5400174
[2,] 0.5400174 1.0000000 0.5400174
[3,] 0.5400174 0.5400174 1.0000000
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, sorry for the problem with the data set. However, I'm not entirely sure how this helps me in this case. You say an offset is measured without variability, I really want to look for a beta coefficient giving me the effect of a treatment compared to the "placebo". Can you clarify this please?

Comment: This shows that the offset function can be used in your chosen computational mechanism ( function `gee::gee`). Most discussions of the analysis of non-inferiority designs with binary outcomes assume a simple test of difference in proportions rather than using the "treatment" as a covariate in a regression model. I think you might add the offset conditional on the treatment assignment, but I have not yet found an online citation to support that approach without paying a fee. The example I offered does not yield an estimate for the one-sided test you propose.

Comment: These responses from Thomas Lumley and Russ Lenth, both highly respected statisticians and R package authors, might be useful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/502034/should-you-always-weight-observations-by-exposure-in-a-poisson-rate-glm ... and ... https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/486095/post-hoc-analysis-after-glm-model-using-count-data-and-offset